# Case-Case Cox Regression

Tags: r, dataframe, cox-regression

My data has only disease status from Baseline to Follow-up72 as well as Visiting time series is also in the form of Baseline to Follow-up72. How would i run cox regression analysis?

**My data :**

**Sample    AGE VisBL   VisFU6  VisFU12 VisFU24 VisFU36 VisFU48 VisFU60 VisFU72 BL  FU12    FU24    FU36    FU48    FU60    FU72**
1001    70  30/07/2010  29/01/2011  30/07/2011  11/07/2012  06/08/2013  30/06/2014  18/07/2016      PD  PD  PDD PD-MCI  PD-MCI  .   PD-MCI

2002    67  04/05/2010  08/11/2010  15/06/2011  24/07/2012  25/07/2013  27/06/2014  28/04/2015      PD  PD  PDD PD  PD  PD  .

3003    68  09/09/2010  16/03/2011  11/10/2011  06/11/2012  01/10/2013  21/10/2014          PD  PD  PD  PD  PDD .   .

Vis = Visit
BL, FU12, FU24, FU36, FU48, FU60, FU72 = Disease status(All of them are diseased, no control are present)

PD= Parkinson disease, PDD = Parkinson disease demetia, PD-MCI = Parkinsons disease Mild cognitive impairment.

Any piece of advise is beneficial.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In particular, please read the information on how to prssent your data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.